# cakephp 3 paginator doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I'm curently using this query with Cakephp 3 for a little search engine

```
$query_tweet = $this->Tweet
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'Users.username',
        'Users.avatarprofil',
        'Tweet.contenu_tweet',
        'Tweet.created',
        'Tweet.nb_commentaire',
        'Tweet.nb_partage',
        'Tweet.nb_like',
    ])
    ->where([
        "MATCH(Tweet.contenu_tweet) AGAINST(:search)" 
    ])
    ->where(['private' => 0]) // on ne cherche que les tweets publics
    ->bind(':search', '$search')
    ->order(['Tweet.created' => 'DESC'])
    ->contain(['Users']);
```

This query works perfectly but i want to use the paginator like this

```
$this->set('resultat_tweet', $this->Paginator->paginate($query_tweet, ['limit' => 8]));
```

i get

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT
    Users.username AS `Users__username`,
    Users.avatarprofil AS `Users__avatarprofil`,
    Tweet.contenu_tweet AS `Tweet__contenu_tweet`,
    Tweet.created AS `Tweet__created`,
    Tweet.nb_commentaire AS `Tweet__nb_commentaire`,
    Tweet.nb_partage AS `Tweet__nb_partage`,
    Tweet.nb_like AS `Tweet__nb_like` 
FROM
    tweet Tweet 
    LEFT JOIN
        users Users ON Users.username = (Tweet.user_id)
WHERE (
    MATCH(Tweet.contenu_tweet) AGAINST(:search) 
    AND private = :c0
)
ORDER BY
    Tweet.created DESC
LIMIT
    8 OFFSET 0
```

i tried this query in PHPmyadmin and it works, i have many tests to see if i get the search and i have it

i really dont know what's the problem , i 'm using the Paginator on others pages and it work

Comment: I suspect that the paginator is cloning the query and during the cloning the bounding variable is lost. This might be a bug that should be reported in the github issues and not on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for this error? The query is run twice by paginator. One for `$query->all()` and again for `$cleanQuery->count()`. I want to know if it is failing for the second `count()` call. See `Paginator.php` around line 118.

Comment: I saw on line 186 of Paginator.php                                         $cleanQuery = clone $query;
         $results = $query->all();
         $numResults = count($results);
         $count = $cleanQuery->count();                                                                                               i think you are right, the bounding variable is lost

Comment: @christ57 I just tested your query on my own CakePHP 3.5.2 and it works.

Comment: The error message is a hint. It means that there is an **extra** binding on the query. I suspect that the query isn't as you have it pasted in the question. Can you modify `Paginator.php` with `dd($query->__toString())` and see what the SQL really is.

Comment: Keep in mind that Paginator will *add* conditions from the controller's paginate property. Maybe there is a collision happening with the conditions.

Comment: The query works perfectly in the view, however i get the message when i want to use the paginator on this query, with the dd($query->__toString()), i get the exact same as the sql query of the question

Comment: Can you try `dd($query->getValueBinder()->bindings())`. That will show what bindings there are in the query.

Comment: i guess that's it  :  /src/Datasource/Paginator.php (line 184)

object(Cake\Database\ValueBinder) {
 [protected] _bindings => []
 [protected] _bindingsCount => (int) 0
}

Comment: interesting.... are you conditionally adding bindings? Maybe there is a logic problem.

Comment: Yes , before the query i'm checking if the variable is empty but i'm not conditionnally adding binding, currently trying new logic but still the same error, maybe the paginator can't be use with this kind of variable

Comment: I tested your code with paginator on my project. Works as expected. I suspect the issue is before you call paginate. I would update the question with all of the code related to building the query.

Comment: you were right, the problem was before the call, however that doesn't work totally because he can't return the right URL with <?= $this->Paginator->next('Next page'); ?> The current URL is http://localhost/instatux/search-test and he give me http://localhost/instatux/search?page=2

Comment: Trying to use   <?= $this->Paginator->options([
    'url' => ['-'.$search.'']
        
    ]); and i get http://localhost/instatux/search/index/%2Fsearch-test?page=2 but i want http://localhost/instatux/search-test?page=2, trying to use an horrible solution like  echo str_replace('index/','',$this->Paginator->next('Next page')); ?> but that doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly, i get what i want by creating a new route, i don't use anymore str_replace

final code

```
              <?= $this->Paginator->options([
'url' => ['-'.$search.'']

]);

       echo $this->Paginator->next('Next page'); ?>
```

and the new route

```
Router::connect('/search/index/-:string',['controller' => 'Search', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Thanks a lot to everyone who helped me , especially Mathew Foscarini