# cakephp 3 paginator doesn't work with a specific query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, paginator

In this previous subject [cakephp 3 paginator doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331687/cakephp-3-paginator-doesnt-work), i had an issue with the paginator in a Cakephp 3 who gave med an error, but this time i have no error, absolutly nothing with this query

```
    $tweet_comm = $this->Tweet->find() 

    ->where(['Tweet.id' => $this->request->getParam('id')])

    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->contain(['Commentaires'=> function($q) { 
          return $q->order(['Commentaires.created' => 'DESC']);
      }])
    ->contain(['Commentaires.Users']);

    $this->set('tweet', $this->Paginator->paginate($tweet_comm, ['limit' => 8]));
```

this query works perfectly in the view but i want to paginate it, when i tried to use `Paginator->next('Next page'); ?> he gave me the current page without any page 2

i suspect a problem with the contain 
`

Comment: I expect your query to give you just one record. So there is nothing to paginate. But maybe you want to paginate the comments related to the tweet. Then you don't have to find the tweets but the comments: `$this->Commentaires->find()`

Comment: that's what i thought but with this query, i have all details on the tweet and all the comments, everything in one query but i guess you are right i need to separate

Comment: actually cake performs two queries anyway, as you have already noticed

Comment: yes you are right, i changed and everything is working perfectly , thanks a lot arilia